# How to change the colour of an icon at some condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, icons

I have a Linkbutton in which I am using an awesome icon.
I want to change the colour of the icon at some condition in C# server-side code.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="TemplateEditLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="TemplateEdit" CssClass="btn grid-btn-link">
    <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true'></i> 
    <span>Edit</span>                                                                             
</asp:LinkButton>                



 LinkButton templateEditLinkButton = e.Row.FindControl("TemplateEditLinkButton");
    if ((e.Row.Cells[10].Text == "False")) {
        //here;change color condition
    }

}
```

Comment: please try the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ternary operator to check condition inside html control on razor pages like.

**Inside code behind**

```
protected bool isColorchange { get; set; }
```

**Then in action**

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     LinkButton templateEditLinkButton = 
    e.Row.FindControl("TemplateEditLinkButton");
      if ((e.Row.Cells[10].Text == "False")) {
              this.isColorchange = true;
      }
       else{
       this.isColorchange=false; 
       }

  }
```

**View**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="TemplateEditLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="TemplateEdit" 
CssClass="btn grid-btn-link">
<i class='<%= (isColorchange==true?"classone":"classtwo") %>' aria-hidden='true'></i> 
<span>Edit</span>                                                                             
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

Please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

Comment: please first tell me the condition on which you want to change the behaviour

Comment: can you please show me that what is commandname ? and are you passing this into the razor page?

Comment: i am using asp.net

Comment: I know you are using asp.net webform ,let me know what is the "commandname" here ,without giving definition of this code i cannot conclude myselft.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178175/discussion-between-taha-sultan-temuri-and-deepak-jain).

Comment: please accept the answer if you think it is correct.